# sql query. Associated with multiple tables

Tags: sql, database

Having this problem, I don `t know how to pull data from multiple tables. I tried to use INNER JOIN and UNION.
Here is what I came so far:

```
select `name_ganre` from `teleprogram`.`ganres`
where `idganre`=any(select `idganre` from `teleprogram`.`ganre-transfer` 
where `idtransfer`=any(select `idtransfer` from `teleprogram`.`broadcasting`));

select `name_channel` from `teleprogram`.`channel` 
where `idchannel`= any(select `idchannel` from `teleprogram`.`broadcasting`);
```

I need to bring in one column name of the channel. And another name for the genre.

```
broadcasting 
rows: idtransfer, idchannel

transfer
rows: idtransfer, name_transfer

ganre-transfer
rows: idganre, idtransfer

ganre
rows: idganre, name_ganre

channels
rows: idchannel, name_channel
```

I'm trying to get the data through broadcasting. May be simplified?
After the query: name_channel, name_ganre

Thank you!

Comment: Which table is the "main" (or "parent") table? Are there always matching rows in all other tables for each row in the main table?

Comment: Note that because you can have multiple genres for each channel, you will probably get multiple rows for some channels (one row per channel, per genre).

Comment: @Bohemian: There's a many-to-many relationship here, not a parent-child relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you need is this:

```
select c.name_channel, g.name_ganre
from channels c
inner join broadcasting b on b.idchannel = c.idchannel
inner join ganre-transfer gt on gt.idtransfer = b.idtransfer
inner join ganre g on g.idganre = gt.idganre
```

You can see how `INNER JOIN` works [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)!